# Enable CROS in Lumen 9.1.2

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

please can you explain me how can i enable CROS in Lumen step by step, am new in lumen and i done my api, but am trying consum from remote host and CRON is blocked, plis help.

error:
`Access to fetch at 'http://api.alopez.es/users/login' from origin 'http://web.alopez.es:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

as this [Documents](https://www.codementor.io/@chiemelachinedum/steps-to-enable-cors-on-a-lumen-api-backend-e5a0s1ecx)

make new middleware CorsMiddleware

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class CorsMiddleware
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'      => '*',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'     => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => 'true',
            'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => '86400',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'     => 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
        ];

        if ($request->isMethod('OPTIONS'))
        {
            return response()->json('{"method":"OPTIONS"}', 200, $headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        {
            $response->header($key, $value);
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

and Register your new middleware
Head over to your bootstrap/app.php file and register your new middleware with the following lines:

```
$app->middleware([
    App\Http\Middleware\CorsMiddleware::class
 ]);
```

Comment: I do bat not working. I create CorsMiddleware.php in app/Http/Middleware/ and add the middlware in top of bootstrap/app.php bottom of $app = new ... and not working :(